# How to explode link in php and put in array and transform in JSON

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, image

Example:

```
<img src="../uploads/images/nameimage-nameitem1-22-33-nameitem2-55-44.png">
<button >Edit image</button>

Array:
image: nameitem1
x: 22
y: 33

Image: nameitem2
x:55
y:44


<img src="../uploads/images/nameimage-nameitem1-18-43-nameitem2-29-40-nameitem3-35-46-nameitem4-38-16-nameitem4-27-36-nameitem5-40-10.png">
<button>Edit image</button>

Array:
image: nameitem1
x: 18
y: 43

Image: nameitem2
x:29
y:40

Image: nameitem3
x:35
y:46.... etc.
```

I need to transform link when click "edit image" in JSON and to recover informations at the Jquery variables.

I know I'll need to use the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), but how to explode link in php and put in array?

---

**EDITED**

With this regular expression I can only get the image url

```
%<img.*?src=["\'](.*?)["\'].*?/>%i
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: can't you just use explode('-', $src) in php (where $src is the image url) and parse the result?

Comment: Thanks. My doubt is how to create a properly sorted array for each value: image, x and y. And then be able to create the json

Comment: If I explode using only the reference "-" as will correctly classify the values in the array to image, x and y?